# Как сделать nav-link active по всей высоте nav-pills [Bootstrap 4]

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap4, navigationbar

Как сделать красную кнопку на всю высоту, чтобы не было отступов, но при этом остальные элементы меню были все идеально по горизонтали?

На этот скриншоте то, как я хочу сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на этом скриншоте текущее положение дел:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую html, css и фреймворк bootstrap 4.

```css
.nav-link, a {
  color: #bab2b2;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.nav-link:hover, a:hover {
  color: #d2af30;
}
.nav-pills {
  background: #060606;
}
#active, #active:hover, #active:focus {
  background-color: rgb(170, 32, 32);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Belkin Dmitriy</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="active" href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">BIO</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CREATION</a>
          </li>
  </ul>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.nav-link, a {
  color: #bab2b2;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.nav-link:hover, a:hover {
  color: #d2af30;
}
.nav-pills {
  background: #060606;
}
#active, #active:hover, #active:focus {
  background-color: rgb(170, 32, 32);
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show>.nav-link{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 23px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-grid/bootstrap-grid.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="active" href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">BIO</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">CREATION</a>
          </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```